# For making certain that a field is visible is there anything beside .show()?

Tags: jquery

I have a div that I turn invisible under certain circumstances. Other parts of the code need it visible under any circumstance. Now I use the following 2 statements for the appropriate parts:

```
$("#mydiv").hide()  // Make invisible
$("#mydiv").show() // Make visible
```

My question is: Is using .show() appropraite even if it can be that when I reacht the corresponding code part that it is visible anyway  or should I do some visibility check there first before using .show() and if so which one?

Comment: `$("#mydiv:hidden").show()` but there isn't really any purpose for that, just call `show()`

Answer (score 0):

Internally, JQuery does the check for you when applying show/hide. So you do not need to check again yourself.

If you would like to check if the element is visible, you would do like so:

```
$('#mydiv').is(':visible');//Returns true or false.
```

Reference: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bb4d888f4f7886371347b59eae5d4e6135acb7ed/src/css.js#L154

Answer (score 0):

If you call `.show()`on an element that is already visible, nothing will happen. It's absolutely fine.

You could do the following if you wanted:

```
var $mydiv = $("#mydiv");

if ( $mydiv.css("display") === "hidden" ) $mydiv.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery (2.13) show's source code:

```
show: function() {
        return showHide( this, true );
    }

function showHide( elements, show ) {
    var display, elem, hidden,
        values = [],
        index = 0,
        length = elements.length;

    for ( ; index < length; index++ ) {
        elem = elements[ index ];
        if ( !elem.style ) {
            continue;
        }

        values[ index ] = data_priv.get( elem, "olddisplay" );
        display = elem.style.display;
        if ( show ) {
            // Reset the inline display of this element to learn if it is
            // being hidden by cascaded rules or not
            if ( !values[ index ] && display === "none" ) {
                elem.style.display = "";
            }

            // Set elements which have been overridden with display: none
            // in a stylesheet to whatever the default browser style is
            // for such an element
            if ( elem.style.display === "" && isHidden( elem ) ) {
                values[ index ] = data_priv.access( elem, "olddisplay", defaultDisplay(elem.nodeName) );
            }
        } else {
            hidden = isHidden( elem );

            if ( display !== "none" || !hidden ) {
                data_priv.set( elem, "olddisplay", hidden ? display : jQuery.css( elem, "display" ) );
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the display of most of the elements in a second loop
    // to avoid the constant reflow
    for ( index = 0; index < length; index++ ) {
        elem = elements[ index ];
        if ( !elem.style ) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( !show || elem.style.display === "none" || elem.style.display === "" ) {
            elem.style.display = show ? values[ index ] || "" : "none";
        }
    }

    return elements;
}
```

It does some checking before doing things, however if you really need performance that it can't hurt to check for the visibility before.